# How to select checkboxes based on text content?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, checked

I have a table with multiple checkboxes. In JavaScript/JQuery I want to select all of them but a couple based on the text content in that table data. So, it should select all checkboxes except if the text content is equal to '899', etc. This is what I have currently:

```
$('#select-all').click(function (event) {
    if (this.checked) {
        var items = document.getElementsByClassName('col-store_number');
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].textContent === 899) {
                items[i].checked = false;
            } else {
                items[i].checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When I check the select all box it doesn't select anything, so its likely making them all false instead of just the 899 one. I did a console.log(items[i].textContent); and it did return the right values, so I'm getting the right text content.

Here is what the table looks like -

```
<td class="col-store_number">899</td>
```

And here is the checkbox -

```
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="94" id="id_94" class="checkbox admin__control-checkbox" checked="checked">
```

Comment: It still does the same thing when I add the quotes, or use parseInt

Comment: Please share the html , it is not possible to know what `items[i].textContent` means since you want to get the text of checkbox

Comment: I think the problem is actually checking the box, not the `if` statement. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery

Comment: I have updated my question with the table information.

Comment: Do you have the checkbox elements in a neighboring cell to the text?

Comment: Yes - I realize now that I need to find the checkboxes after my if test, or something like that

Comment: Please share a portion of the html table with relevant data to the exercise

Answer (score 1):

( *I deleted my **first** faulty attempt here* )

The **second version** was:

If the checkbox is found in the cell immediately following the cell containing the text then you should do the following (edited - now everything is done "in one line"):

```
$('#select-all').click(function () {
    $('td.col-store_number:not(:contains(899))')
      .next().find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked)
});
```

And a slightly improved **third version** is here (working demo, using ES6 code):

```js
$('#select-all').click(function () {
   $('td.col-store_number')
      .filter((i,el)=>el.textContent!='899')
      .parent().find('input:checkbox')
      .prop('checked', this.checked)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
master switch:<input type="checkbox" id="select-all" checked="checked">
<table>
<tr><td class="col-store_number">899</td><td>Some other content</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="94" id="id_90" class="checkbox admin__control-checkbox" checked="checked"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="col-store_number">4711</td><td>and more content</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="94" id="id_91" class="checkbox admin__control-checkbox" checked="checked"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="col-store_number">899</td><td>other content</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="94" id="id_92" class="checkbox admin__control-checkbox" checked="checked"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="col-store_number">0815</td><td>yet some more</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="94" id="id_93" class="checkbox admin__control-checkbox" checked="checked"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="col-store_number">899</td><td>here too</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="94" id="id_94" class="checkbox admin__control-checkbox" checked="checked"></td><td>Just for the sake of it</td></tr>
<tr><td class="col-store_number">007</td><td>yeah, and here.</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="94" id="id_95" class="checkbox admin__control-checkbox" checked="checked"></td><td>there can be text here too ...</td></tr>
<tr><td class="col-store_number">53</td><td>I am</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="94" id="id_96" class="checkbox admin__control-checkbox" checked="checked"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="col-store_number">899</td><td>getting tired</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="94" id="id_97" class="checkbox admin__control-checkbox" checked="checked"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="col-store_number">1899</td><td>of this</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="94" id="id_98" class="checkbox admin__control-checkbox" checked="checked"></td><td>extra checkbox:</td></tr>
<tr><td class="col-store_number">8995</td><td>...</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="94" id="id_99" class="checkbox admin__control-checkbox" checked="checked"></td><td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td></tr>
</table>
```

This latest version is a bit more tolerant as to the table layout: it looks for all cell of class "col-store_number" having a text content different from `899` and sets/unsets the tick marks for all checkboxes found in the same table row.

Comment: When I try this, the 'select all' checkbox only selects or unselects itself. It does not effect the other checkboxes.

Comment: No, a check-box - like all `<input>` elements - is an [empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/empty_element); therefore it cannot contain text, or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example:

https://codebrace.com/editor/b1da3a821

Instead of `textContent`  you should use `value` to get the values inside input type. The value is usually in string format.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select-all').click(function (event) {
        var items = document.getElementsByClassName('col-store_number');

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].value == "899") {
                items[i].checked = false;
            } else {
                items[i].checked = true;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

or you could use `parseInt(items[i].value) === 899`, if you really want to check the value with an Integer.

I hope you were expecting this! :)